# How to skip the messages shown by linux when redirected the output of the vim into a file

Tags: linux, vim, cron, stderr

I am running a script on linux environment and havd putted this cron :-

the cron returns a message in mail like

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

how can i skip these types of messages ?

Comment: you use vi/vim in crontab ? are you sure ? usually people use sed/ed.

Comment: What commands are you running (in your script or cron) to get this warning messages?
Vi is a interactive text editor, that is not intended to be used in scripts. Text-processing tools will work better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside for a moment the question raised by your question -- "Why are you running `vim` in a cron job?"

To answer your actual question, those warnings are being sent to `stderr`.  To suppress them, redirect standard error to `/dev/null`:

```
vim arg1 arg2 arg3 2> /dev/null
```